# how does mouse event work in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i am developing a java web application using primefaces 4.0 and jsf 2.0.
i have a text label and it's textbox.  when user is in edit mode, and want to modify the value of a particular textbox, the old value of the textbox should be displayed on the right side while the user is entering the new value in the textbox. so i add an output text which rendered false on load. i want to trigger this output text(id="test") when the user click in the textbox(id="customer_customername"). so rendered should be change to equal. anyone can tell me how to do this? in my backend i have an interface with its implementation , dao and service.

```xml
<h:panelGrid id="detail1" columns="2" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="label,value">

     <h:outputText value="#{customermsgs['customer.customername.title']}:" />

     <h:inputText id="customer_customername" value="#   {CustomerComponent.customer.customername}" onclick="#{CustomerComponent.customername}" label="customer_customername">
          <f:ajax render="detail1" />
     </h:inputText>

     <h:outputText id="test" value="#{CustomerComponent.customer.customername}"    rendered="#{CustomerComponent.visible}"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

```java
public class CustomerComponentImpl implements CustomerComponent {

/**
 * Data type variable that provides CRUD operations for Customer entities
 * 
 */


private boolean visible=false;

private String customername;


    public String getCustomername() {
    return customername;
}

public void setCustomername(String customername) {
    setVisible(true);
    this.customername = customername;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

    //some codes goes here.
```

Note: i have implemented the method in my interface also.

the onclick event is not working. look like it does not trigger! anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

This,

```
<h:inputText ... onclick="#{CustomerComponent.customername}">
```

does very definitely not what you thought it does. In its current form, when filled, it would only cause a JavaScript error because the `#{CustomerComponent.customername}` does very likely not return a piece of (syntactically valid!) JavaScript code which should be executed on click. Instead, it's more likely to return a string representing the customer name. When printed this into JavaScript context, it would only be interpreted as an undefined JavaScript variable.

As to your concrete functional requirement, the `<f:ajax>` listens inside input components by default only on `change` event. You can change this to `click` by setting the `event` attribute accordingly. All in all, this should do as you intented:

```
<h:inputText id="customer_customername" value="#{CustomerComponent.customer.customername}" label="customer_customername">
    <f:ajax event="click" render="detail1" />
</h:inputText>
```